# Upgraded from Rails 4 to 6: uninitialized constant ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::SchemaCache

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6

I upgraded a rather old app from rails 4.2 to 6.1.3.1. The app runs fine locally, but when I try to deploy it to my server using capistrano I get the error below. It states that

```
NameError: uninitialized constant ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::SchemaCache 
     ** Did you mean?  ActiveRecord::Schema
```

This occurs when running bundle exec rake assets:precompile either via capistrano or manually on the server. I've tried setting some flags in application.rb like:

```
config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false
```

However this did not fix the issue. I feel like I've exhausted my knowledge and search skills. Could someone help point me in the right direction please?

```
  * executing "cd -- /home/user/app_rails6/releases/20210419123208 && RAILS_ENV=staging RAILS_GROUPS=assets bundle exec rake assets:precompile"
  * executing command
 ** rake aborted! 
 ** NameError: uninitialized constant ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::SchemaCache 
 ** Did you mean?  ActiveRecord::Schema
 **  
 ** /home/user/app_rails6/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.3.1/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:139:in `block (3 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
 **  
 ** /home/user/app_rails6/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.3.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:71:in `class_eval'
 **  
 ** /home/user/app_rails6/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.3.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:71:in `block in execute_hook'
 ** /home/user/app_rails6/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.3.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:61:in `with_execution_control'
------trace truncated by author------
```

Update:

Update: When I use an environment which uses sqlite as the database, the command runs fine. When I use an environment which uses postgres as the database I get the error.

Comment: What guides were u following to do this upgrade? It's generalaly advised to first move to Rails 5 and then 6 afaik

Comment: Yep - I went to 5 first.

Comment: Is Zeitwerk enabled? # config/application.rb
config.load_defaults 6.0 # enables zeitwerk mode in CRuby

Comment: I have config.load_defaults 6.0 in my application.rb file. Any other ideas @Joel_Blum

Comment: Let's try to narrow it down a bit. Do u get this error on Rails 5? Also, on Rails 6, if you run the precompile task on your own machine (RAILS_ENV=development) does it give the same error?

Comment: Thanks! If I run RAILS_ENV=development then it works fine. If I change the environment to test or staging it gives the error listed in my first post.

I didn't try to deploy the app whilst it was on 5. I just tested it worked locally and progressed to 6.

Comment: @Joel_Blum I tested on rails 5.2.5 and asset:precompile works fine. I'm going to try and take my rails 6 branch to an older rails version and see if that helps.

Comment: You can try running bin/rails zeitwerk:check . It seems like something in the move from the old autoloader to zeitwerk may be causing this https://guides.rubyonrails.org/autoloading_and_reloading_constants.html#differences-with-classic-mode

Comment: I ran zeitwerk:check and it said everything was fine. It's funny on 6.0.3.6 it works fine. On 6.1.0 and above it is broken. Not sure why.

Comment: that's really strange. how about opening an issue on rails?

Comment: That's exactly what I've done. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out there was a bug in Rails and this has now been fixed on 6.1.3.1 (the 6-1-stable branch).

I'm still having issues with a slightly different error, but this one has been resolved.